# How to receive post request on web page?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to receive the post request on a web page while my page isn't refreshing or is still or just open, sort of concept like dynamic messages without refreshing the page. I don't want to pull it using ajax

I tried sending request to that URL but that doesn't work. I wanted to know a way to receive a post data and display it to user.
Any help is appreciated.

I read about amazon sns push for http/s, but they too doesn't send request to each browser page. they just send the request to the server, how should i make things in a way that , that post request from amazon goes to every browser page wherever it is open and display the content in the post message.

Comment: This SO thread explains all the possibilities in depth: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)? It is basically a protocol used to send information from server to client without the need for the client to make a request. Similar to what chats systems like facebook messenger use, it stops the client having to poll a server for data.

Comment: There is a PHP library for working with WebSockets https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/